# Speedup of DimensionReduce

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, machine-learning

I am interested in accelerating DimensionReduce using the "TSNE" method. I have a matrix with a size of 30000 * 10, and I want to reduce to 30000 * 8. But the calculation is very slow, any suggestions on how to speed up the calculation. Currently, I do it in the following manner:

```
data={{0.0136704, 868., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0.0679724, 1.02337, 5., 
  2391.}, {0.0327273, 65., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0615385, 1.02337, 5., 
  2391.}, {0.0343137, 45., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.0888889, 0.976633, 3., 
  2388.}, {0.0425656, 358., 11., 0.0333333, 0., 0., 0.0642458, 
  0.976633, 3., 2375.}, {0.0146471, 168., 4., 0.4, 0., 0., 0.0892857, 
  1.02337, 5., 2378.}, {0.0255665, 362., 6., 0.0833333, 0., 0., 
  0.0856354, 1.02337, 5., 2368.}, {0.0215647, 443., 5., 0.0967742, 0.,
   0., 0.0857788, 1.02337, 5., 2377.}, {0.0242424, 435., 6., 
  0.0294118, 0., 0., 0.110345, 0.976633, 3., 2362.}, {0.0311943, 511.,
   22., 0., 0., 0., 0.129159, 1.02337, 5., 2360.}, {0.030086, 171., 
  4., 0., 0., 0., 0.122807, 1.02337, 5., 2361.}, {0.0324948, 222., 
  10., 0., 0., 0., 0.103604, 0.976633, 3., 2364.}, {0.0232975, 120., 
  2., 0., 0., 0., 0.108333, 1.02337, 5., 2380.}, {0.046616, 632., 20.,
   0., 0., 0., 0.056962, 1.02337, 5., 2354.}, {0.0187225, 381., 9., 
  0., 0., 0., 0.0603675, 1.02337, 5., 2342.}, {0.0234043, 421., 11., 
  0.133333, 0., 0., 0.109264, 1.02337, 5., 2384.}, {0.0255072, 375., 
  8., 0., 0., 0., 0.0906667, 1.02337, 5., 2359.}, {0.0284264, 240., 
  15., 0.125, 0., 0., 0.129167, 1.02337, 5., 2344.}, {0.0246575, 183.,
   5., 0., 0., 0., 0.0819672, 1.02337, 5., 2361.}, {0.0155535, 251., 
  4., 0., 0., 0., 0.0876494, 0.0233665, 4., 2351.}, {0.0232186, 276., 
  10., 0., 0., 0., 0.0688406, 1.02337, 5., 2346.}}


   DimensionReduce[data, 8, Method -> {"TSNE", "Perplexity" -> 50}, 
    TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.290914, Null}


   DimensionReduce[data, 8, Method -> {"TSNE", "Perplexity" -> 50}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.307318, Null}
```

Comment: This might be slightly offtopic for this site, but on topic for what you want to do. If you like t-SNE you might want to check out [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ([github repo](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap), [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426)). It offers the best of both worlds, global feature preserving methods like singular value decomposition and local feature preserving methods like t-SNE. Also it converges faster than t-SNE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Singular value decomposition may provide a reasonable dimension reduction.

```
rankreduce[A_?MatrixQ, rank_Integer] := 
 Module[{U, Σ, V, r},
  r = Min[Max[1, rank], Min[Dimensions[A]]];
  {U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A, r];
  U.Σ.V\[Transpose]
  ]
```

Let's simulate a compressible data set `A`:

```
n = 30000;
m = 10;
rank = 8;
SeedRandom[123];
A = Dot[
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m}],
   RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[m]] Exp[-Range[1, m]]
   ];
```

And let's see how it works:

```
A2 = rankreduce[A, rank]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.006426

Checking the relative errors:

```
Norm[A2 - A, ∞]/Norm[A, ∞]
Norm[A2 - A, "Frobenius"]/Norm[A, "Frobenius"]
Norm[A2 - A]/Norm[A]
```

> 0.000324675
>
> 0.000332843
>
> 0.000336114

Of course, the success of the method depends heavily on your data and your actual application. What is performed here is a least-squares fit to an 8-dimension linear subspace, so no sophisticated nonlinear model is developed. But with only 10 data points, it really does not make sense to fit against a complicated nonlinear manifold.

## Edit

The following function is even 4 times faster than `rankreduce` for this use case. But as it employs the eigenvector decomposition of the matrix `Transpose[A].A`, this may result in precision issues (`Transpose[A].A` may have considerably larger condition number than `A`).

```
rankreduce2[A_?MatrixQ, rank_Integer] := Module[{λ, U, r},
  r = Min[Max[1, rank], Min[Dimensions[A]]];
  If[Dimensions[A][[1]] > Dimensions[A][[2]],
   {λ, U} = Eigensystem[A\[Transpose].A, r];
   (A.U\[Transpose]).U
   ,
   {λ, U} = Eigensystem[A.A\[Transpose], r];
   U\[Transpose].(U.A)
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Actually, `SingularValueDecomposition` is very fast, if you only need the largest N singular values: e.g. `SingularValueDecomposition[A, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming` only takes a few milliseconds to calculate the largest 10 singular values

Comment: @NikiEstner Ah, very good point; I forgot about limiting the rank in the first place!